# Android webview zooming in relative layout

Tags: android, webview, android-relativelayout, zooming

I have a RelativeLayout and there is a WebView inside it. After I zoom in and zoom out, my WebView isn't in center. When I include another view into my RelativeLayout I can't place the WebView in center. 
Can anyone please suggest anything??
any help is appreciated

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fullscreen_image_parrent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true">
</WebView>

<include layout="@layout/full_image_controls"/>
```

Comment: set fill_parent to RelativeLayout and what is in full_image_controls layout please put the full_image_controls layout code here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `orientation` tag in `RelativeLayout`. And another thing..did you try to set your layout width and height params to `fill_parent`. I'm not really sure about it,but in some situations I had almost the same problem with alignments on my views just because my `RelativeLayout` was using `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`.

Comment: I've already lost my hope to receive an answer! After I got the zoom working there was a strange issue: the image was kind of jumping when zooming it. anyway, thank you very much )